# Filter row and populate

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a form response sheet with different columns. I have a region column for every country. But when you respond to the form you have to select only one country. So in my sheet every row has only one country column filled. I would like to filter every row (and populate to automatically have new responses filtered) to have a new column with the region selected.

[Sheet expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaQxy.png)
In this case I only have 3 countries but in the real case I have about 40 countries.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please provide more info, I understand you have a form and the results of the form go to the sheet. How do you want it to be filtered if the sheet gets every form submit, or you create a sheet for each submit? Thanks

Comment: @Kessy No when I have a new person submitting my form, the sheet linked has a new row inserted with all the responses of the person.So all the responses are on a same sheet

Comment: Then could you provide the form to test it? If not try setting up a filter view. Each time you add a new row the filter applies to it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try on row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C);;999^99))))
```

Comment: It worked thanks !
Could you explain me the formula ? especially the 999^99

Comment: 999^99 its just a big number. can be any number you wish just needs to be higher than all rows in the sheet so the query would work correctly and smash all columns into single one